# How can I cover a window in a nice way

Tags: wood, desk, cover

I have my gaming place and workplace in front of a window because this is the most convenient and silent place I can have it in my apartment. However, The back of my screens is visible to the outside world to everyone who is walking past.

So what I want to do it is to cover it till the height of the tallest screen and end it with a plank where I can put figurines on and maybe a small plant or two for decoration. What should I use to cover it so I can achieve this?

The window is a two-part in a wooden carcass, the blinds that are currently on it will be replaced so I don't need to keep them in account.

Attached picture: [image: My current working/gaming space]

Comment: seems primarily opinion based, I'g go with some sort of film - like window tint but opaque or translucent. we have it on some of the glass in my office. talk to a window expert.

Comment: Does the building have a code limiting the way one can cover a window so as to maintain a uniform look from outside?

Comment: You can attach a wooden back splash to your desk top. Use L brackets which can be screwed to the underside of the desktop and back of the back splash. The back splash can be a nice piece of wood or a piece of plywood that you cover with cork or something decorative. You can add a shelf to the top with L brackets or use decorative brackets.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: They make these things called curtains....

Comment: What is on the back of your screens that you do not want people see If they *could* see them from that building far over there?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider just applying some of that opaquing film to the window glass that just goes part way up. You wouldn't get your plant shelf but this would be an easy solution to the people looking in.

Since you live in an apartment your range of options of that you can do are limited unless this is a unit that you actually own. And even in the case that you do own you would not want to go so far as modifying things in a way that they are not reversible without damage.

One scheme that should work would be to look into using a sheet of the dense pink or blue rigid foam insulating material that is cut to length so that it fits across the window opening with a push-in friction fit. This material comes in large panel sizes (in USA ~4 feet by ~8 feet) so you could achieve the size of covering that you need.

For the shelf it may very well be possible to cut a narrow strip of the same material that fits into the opening and sits flat on the upper edge of the material that covers the window from below. It could bonded or pinned to the lower panel as well.

To improve the look you can try spray painting the foam to a color that coordinates with your room.

Do note that I am not suggesting that you use the lower cost white crumbly foam panels.